# FB.init(), FB.login() and FB.getLoginStatus() methods not giving any response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a webpage and want to include a Facebook share button on it. I am using the following code on page load -

```
$(function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {
         return;
     }
     js = d.createElement(s);
     js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

After that I am calling the FB.init() and FB.login methods as shown below -

```
FB.init({
    appId: '{my App Id}', // App id of my App: Adidas application 
    status: true,
    xfbml: true
});
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
            link: //{my link to post}
        });
    } else {
//Some Error code
    }
}, {
    scope: 'email,user_photos,publish_actions'
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    if(response.status == 'connected') {
        var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        //code to use token
    } else {
//code to do something else
}
});
```

I am looking for pointers as to why it is not giving any response.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the browser’s error console say?

Comment: There is no response on the console. I think I might have missed something, but I am not able to figure out what it is.

Comment: Can you at least highlight if the appropriate function is getting called?

Comment: No function is getting called, I think there is some API change done by facebook...some other apps are also facing the same issue.